# Include external SVG via svg's use and scale

Tags: html, svg

I'm currently giving my debut in svg and am experimenting. I have a HTML file in which I want to include an external svg file via

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       viewbox="0 0 64 64"
       id="parent">
        <use xlink:href="/assets/svg/fingerprint_2.svg#fingerprint"></use>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

fingerprint_2.svg is this file: [file](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxLBpy).

The problem is now, that the external svg is included but doesn't scale to fit the #parent svg. I can't really get my head around whats not working.
The children svg does not apper in its parent, but is shifted to the right and the more I scale the parent svg, the bigger does the children get, and never appears in its parent.

//Edit: Was able to remove the shifting and upscaling through removing the viewbox of the #parent svg element. The problem is still, that the included svg isnt scaling to fit its parent.

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: i provided you with an answer that could probably be used to fix your issue.. but the thing is that you havent provided all the code necessary to see what is really wrong. if you could provide both svg files you are trying to use then that would be great

Comment: Clarified my question a little bit. There is only one html file, wich includes a svg file. The structure of the svg file is viewable at the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

There you go.. 
Just use CSS for that as you don't really have to mess with the `svg` content for styling it. 
and also i would recommend running your svg through a optimizer to get rid of all the unnecessary stuff.

**EDIT**

Now that you have clarified your question, i have rectified my answer.

Remember %'s represent relative values, and px, etc. represent absolute values. 
The problem here is that you are using a width of 100% and height of 100%. If you want to use percentages then you have to have a parent container with defined absolute values.(px vh vw) etc.

So what i have done here is just wrap the svg in a div called parent and gave it a absolute width and height.

Now you can tell the SVG use 100% of that space or whatever you want.

Or you could just change the 100% for whatever predefined value you want.

```css
.parent{
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   id="svg3385"
   viewBox="0 0 431.72714 626.25482"
   version="1.1"
   preserveAspectRatio="none"
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   >
  <g
     transform="translate(-156.01726,-149.49232)"
     id="fingerprint">
    <path
       id="path3388"
       d="m 280.19998,775.09076 c -11.21302,-8.64293 -18.26589,-35.96178 -1.99772,-13.22351 3.37832,3.15831 15.82927,15.39286 1.99772,13.22351 z m 24.3,-2.8 c -21.04752,-11.32941 -31.61258,-35.55989 -40.40552,-56.54106 -8.24773,-26.94689 -6.63023,-54.6773 -13.91533,-81.9321 -5.86259,-8.93273 -1.31664,-47.60933 7.47421,-36.88201 -6.73916,33.6967 6.9808,66.83832 9.62671,100.26394 7.30674,23.50504 15.77516,47.56457 33.78833,65.31103 4.73169,3.68544 15.18383,20.33751 3.4316,9.7802 z m 44.9537,-1.26006 c -3.86515,-11.29677 7.12443,-0.58376 0,0 z m -38.7037,-11.84641 c -19.30205,-19.79792 -28.94414,-47.51377 -36.34318,-73.47169 -5.4558,-26.50588 -11.91276,-52.92625 -9.82475,-80.12033 1.02125,-22.71053 7.20279,-52.09962 24.05926,-66.08084 -6.61157,22.77781 -21.63319,50.03637 -18.35028,77.17321 1.22656,24.59708 4.85583,47.68168 12.61027,71.38096 7.4127,24.13859 16.96914,47.98947 32.29811,68.29033 21.14948,6.23312 1.87989,19.38663 -4.44943,2.82836 z m 30.25,7.10647 c -20.47152,-11.70728 21.22056,-4.1738 0,0 z m 19.23207,-4 c -26.1748,-13.81234 -33.8914,-45.31392 -45.9597,-69.12349 9.23244,-24.76528 26.02691,30.04588 29.23273,42.03078 3.3169,14.21425 25.47597,24.33612 29.14081,29.13532 -4.14052,0.58023 -8.89414,0.59312 -12.41384,-2.04261 z m 31.31064,-2.9309 c 0.64803,-5.53702 5.30151,3.33076 0,0 z m -67.29271,-5.68073 c -16.61229,-19.25131 -23.08336,-44.17747 -31.08689,-67.24707 -3.8568,-23.6419 13.63989,-6.83622 10.5423,6.86914 2.90688,21.7858 28.10714,43.12634 23.13549,62.25508 -0.86363,-0.62572 -1.72727,-1.25143 -2.5909,-1.87715 z m 54.98207,0.61163 c -12.65676,-3.32464 -41.37463,-29.20934 -27.45484,-33.19786 3.06601,13.50849 30.83277,22.00094 27.45484,33.19786 z m 27.26793,0 c -23.81449,-7.25137 -38.13873,-29.92985 -56.91142,-44.49962 18.57705,-1.05866 36.16813,27.81098 55.74044,37.3776 2.94037,2.08693 10.1976,13.49295 1.17098,7.12202 z m -147.36561,-8.02201 c -10.87711,-32.25351 25.161,10.68343 0,0 z m 159.63354,-2.97799 c -12.05726,-2.98898 -44.60937,-25.42358 -29.82916,-28.91759 12.20412,8.33587 32.39727,23.90312 37.49857,30.72604 -2.59682,0.65092 -5.83103,0.43239 -7.66941,-1.80845 z m -174.22522,0.0691 c 1.49586,-5.93369 5.71333,4.45243 0,0 z m -6.79271,-6.91284 c -13.32711,-20.0024 -16.44821,-44.98522 -13.25651,-67.93343 -1.9298,-22.18155 9.48482,-42.23933 9.17576,-64.44179 7.89122,-23.04816 8.07701,-48.68687 21.06449,-70.13399 7.37163,-13.19365 18.4875,-28.54226 34.20355,-26.58139 -2.74386,-17.0899 14.43341,-1.87022 21.45574,-17.99149 25.01671,-15.33705 54.0426,-21.50107 82.54679,-26.70478 40.64698,9.59913 70.54235,40.71552 94.07374,73.44286 19.0733,19.69652 29.13107,46.35883 49.13164,65.21577 8.1868,11.23362 0.59191,28.86681 -7.1452,8.47198 -13.93506,-19.89579 -34.1847,-36.33386 -43.40273,-58.66172 -14.17024,-23.32062 -31.19513,-42.84546 -50.96011,-61.26353 -22.83072,-15.72284 -52.95408,-25.13041 -79.63716,-12.57475 -32.77919,8.3503 -61.7067,29.06181 -78.31482,58.72469 -15.78065,7.01072 20.38407,-36.53894 -5.04823,-14.91576 -17.82881,18.16839 -19.52732,45.52256 -27.52262,68.52708 -2.83121,27.03042 -11.9819,50.59229 -12.89654,77.12228 -1.11923,24.63193 5.35754,49.58055 13.4385,71.94364 l -2.13421,0.23662 -4.77159,-2.48229 -4.9e-4,0 z m 204.05657,2.90562 c -23.3542,-11.78279 -43.28302,-29.39944 -60.8066,-48.13876 -11.41002,-13.32919 8.58741,-32.40018 11.4702,-9.72509 11.52589,26.99457 42.57977,34.94777 57.37479,57.80906 l -2.201,0.80772 -5.83739,-0.75293 0,0 z M 465.71256,732.67 c -5.14756,-17.0915 17.93553,2.11795 0,0 z m -209.04591,-8.04591 c -2.21054,-6.39681 6.32642,2.1387 0,0 z m 186.83333,-6.86781 c -21.1522,-12.51109 -38.68935,-30.00909 -48.56187,-52.57933 -14.36079,-26.75282 -23.2178,-58.53338 -22.51029,-89.63615 10.76324,-7.97646 7.36744,26.84099 13.38534,33.8206 2.28001,25.69183 15.01688,40.96997 23.47026,65.06914 13.79563,15.43472 35.54638,34.94814 52.94769,48.66063 -5.53664,7.02597 -14.7638,0.0962 -18.73113,-5.33489 z m -196.75,0.67337 c -9.39261,-23.76386 -4.10501,-50.04541 -5.77383,-74.89427 11.07321,-4.02471 1.71579,33.04471 9.05893,44.85598 -2.46411,6.93406 16.0595,43.06645 -3.2851,30.03829 z m 230.25,0.99516 c -20.73999,-13.42977 -39.99067,-27.46375 -53.2707,-46.20407 -12.64722,-22.84452 -26.58453,-46.71038 -31.27385,-72.69707 19.86794,-4.18716 11.01135,39.78129 30.68139,45.34288 5.79699,27.48627 32.38169,53.26513 58.54676,65.95073 9.66149,5.57398 5.75753,13.19695 -4.6836,7.60753 z m -100.9826,-7.10154 c -17.84978,-8.04107 -37.01628,-45.43097 -21.65332,-56.4979 11.49929,15.79512 7.08346,39.70211 27.31372,50.87901 -0.0771,1.61853 -3.81283,10.45266 -5.6604,5.61889 z m -165.37792,-2.72636 c -7.38215,-21.67051 3.50219,-44.7923 1.07673,-66.654 -0.94493,-27.08209 9.39298,-53.46012 17.60541,-79.91319 7.56043,-18.41773 -3.60408,-19.05587 -8.05488,-2.0704 -6.75182,21.06443 -14.4049,41.46853 -17.64845,63.89101 -12.07032,15.14617 15.23922,37.17225 -7.83295,49.15693 -24.53324,-24.27025 9.74813,-57.19184 11.272,-85.55158 4.96905,-22.99766 12.33319,-47.03762 33.40613,-60.21345 8.80101,-9.92017 29.33296,-36.63447 35.566,-30.66102 -19.55827,21.04231 -41.80385,41.27816 -42.92302,72.12309 -6.4556,27.86662 -15.69976,54.56769 -15.78278,84.61567 -1.42334,18.49444 -0.54242,37.59878 -6.68419,55.27694 z M 198.8115,660.98522 c 6.41074,-19.22316 -20.3559,8.7007 0,0 z m 142.93848,40.28427 c -14.66943,-19.16865 -16.1902,-43.01884 -15.20994,-65.90995 -2.83019,-12.72973 1.52342,-55.9828 4.9642,-21.47852 1.83745,25.04373 2.68616,53.61021 15.70707,74.5046 4.18183,4.12989 2.87219,27.62981 -5.46133,12.88387 z m 146.70814,3.95354 c 7.13462,-22.09548 -27.98278,-35.80386 -34.55158,-56.95457 -12.62309,-20.42251 -25.42379,-39.70944 -31.44121,-63.01786 -11.04555,-18.20561 -29.00709,-54.00219 -54.50956,-37.0841 -25.85652,16.19368 -19.02895,50.38541 -17.89666,76.0721 5.96706,10.18935 4.35808,36.83602 -7.42929,17.80762 -0.49595,-24.26948 -4.22592,-49.14312 1.05837,-73.15823 6.26201,-19.4855 29.93497,-40.93455 51.32917,-31.48688 24.95327,19.87589 36.28142,50.67658 49.6783,78.65096 13.24151,24.08675 27.15113,47.45195 46.23665,67.57793 9.76587,5.06054 12.25951,24.71475 -2.47419,21.59303 z m -11.95814,-4.93227 c -36.03695,-23.63448 -51.99578,-66.29398 -68.62093,-104.1015 -2.84977,-20.31107 -30.56604,-54.00989 -42.65143,-21.45441 -6.66197,26.7845 8.22053,51.64245 7.95942,76.94567 -13.38485,4.70392 -9.3077,-32.75796 -15.44636,-43.81191 -4.60434,-22.14545 4.90314,-67.21674 35.26045,-50.51848 22.39858,18.60677 23.63802,49.7781 39.57904,72.79285 12.69705,26.96467 31.15444,51.49257 53.57328,70.87434 -1.78619,3.02491 -7.20168,-0.86366 -9.65347,-0.72656 z m 28.49668,-17.81616 c -15.25469,-20.43296 -36.29445,-36.44018 -45.97459,-60.7858 -16.96056,-25.65431 -24.82297,-57.12022 -46.02083,-79.79649 -17.29681,-11.58931 -42.39506,-37.15404 -62.5683,-17.01405 -17.41899,7.30569 -33.85983,41.05934 -42.56242,41.31093 5.69654,-25.43283 28.99854,-45.17858 52.08892,-55.03974 24.03769,-5.51629 41.56242,15.78892 60.68478,26.17923 33.44655,37.16457 41.64527,91.54741 79.42995,125.73946 2.4948,4.72058 26.01399,34.08697 4.92249,19.40646 z m -306.99668,2.23283 c 2.9998,-4.38087 2.55307,5.7242 0,0 z m -3.5,-2.41667 c -0.65022,-8.64435 6.0388,4.72033 0,0 z m 116.10699,-0.58179 c -11.36605,-23.82354 -16.73222,-49.64248 -15.59786,-76.39717 -7.07932,-13.60134 19.43059,-47.36756 9.95386,-17.41588 -4.9504,20.94403 -4.55085,44.50616 -0.44858,65.21276 22.22081,7.94554 -8.33075,-45.03916 12.24749,-37.81343 0.0434,18.06539 2.74158,42.36588 0.94612,57.18793 6.27498,5.40216 -2.10232,9.34966 -7.10103,9.22579 z m -24.9199,-13.22293 c -4.93769,-27.71259 -10.61047,-56.33861 -4.44818,-84.8257 8.87439,-30.91015 28.97425,-59.37512 55.46692,-77.41686 21.17795,-10.7118 47.55755,-21.69772 69.48489,-6.0959 13.1182,6.64036 37.86357,29.93149 28.74423,40.25698 -11.64507,-14.13175 -30.68869,-24.27552 -44.46599,-30.72536 9.55052,-0.45531 27.53458,4.623 8.36615,-5.51328 -18.30067,-8.4301 -39.8314,-2.70555 -56.46425,7.65799 -18.78661,8.64953 -31.38245,27.62084 -41.77434,45.09371 -17.32557,20.6827 -14.77796,52.97046 -11.38545,79.15946 -2.72797,7.16123 13.79468,44.11167 -3.52398,32.40896 z m 85.06291,-0.17966 c -7.56917,-22.10474 27.09698,1.75285 2.49765,2.0481 -0.83255,-0.6827 -1.6651,-1.3654 -2.49765,-2.0481 z m 140.91667,-5.68229 c -16.2412,-21.71029 -32.11843,-43.83919 -46.45508,-66.40923 -5.7913,-13.45298 -28.41676,-44.47326 -19.13565,-50.65961 16.24761,17.88861 24.90424,41.3365 37.83522,62.73397 10.33526,19.60579 27.07198,35.19719 38.56909,53.8009 -2.64332,2.70338 -7.518,0.48712 -10.81358,0.53397 z m 15.84341,-7.31702 c -1.25676,-8.67084 6.29322,2.30138 0,0 z M 175.71256,647.67 c -6.14117,-17.87045 22.18586,-51.31057 9.92478,-57.03067 -3.82284,12.70986 -20.00765,30.02048 -10.65556,5.43317 17.53642,-14.11906 23.49426,-38.10001 37.36741,-53.04847 -9.11508,30.08893 -20.29714,59.84139 -27.57756,90.60112 -1.91231,5.20087 -3.87633,11.16114 -9.05907,14.04485 z m 348,-4 c -10.14802,-21.50659 -30.50539,-36.72197 -39.06965,-58.10434 -20.62381,-17.37452 -23.31547,-46.23487 -43.23664,-64.28978 -17.29567,-18.4864 -37.6812,-39.78648 -65.55953,-36.6446 -26.26803,4.62267 -55.59776,17.39606 -69.8609,40.65937 -9.2036,15.56556 -20.24858,5.24856 -6.02506,-5.46409 19.97199,-26.39569 53.86375,-38.44776 85.83473,-41.46058 30.26048,4.50381 54.73529,24.35674 72.21913,48.49667 15.79203,19.89323 24.81483,44.14338 41.77075,63.32075 2.14667,16.31296 40.286,40.28975 23.92717,53.4866 z M 171.55383,620.37789 c -1.65201,-6.6243 5.49218,1.59953 0,0 z M 312.68531,602.363 c -2.20769,-8.80891 5.85037,-47.36776 6.93623,-19.151 -0.92146,3.80129 -0.48342,23.70132 -6.93623,19.151 z m 231.06467,-9.12663 c -25.84678,-33.86638 -52.64884,-67.04415 -80.08688,-99.56841 -20.12658,-17.48077 -42.72757,-36.58742 -70.89833,-36.93315 -23.21796,-8.45169 -48.02029,-6.86129 -70.46119,2.39575 -24.20608,9.21761 -46.62923,21.82087 -65.57662,39.71448 -14.54663,8.4149 -30.77008,42.36881 -40.66924,35.46527 22.92042,-30.47764 52.05425,-57.20209 86.44226,-74.01955 40.28376,-15.93198 86.53394,-19.21016 127,-2 20.45922,8.81531 36.16224,26.47893 51.84006,41.53206 19.48349,19.23322 33.21996,42.62489 50.93007,62.86561 0.26894,9.56191 36.19969,35.04886 11.47987,30.54794 z m -153.5,-2.35383 c -9.32536,-12.73999 -2.07752,-26.06217 3.8698,-6.8629 2.26179,2.46498 1.21702,13.55314 -3.8698,6.8629 z m -222.78901,-5.65489 c 25.91915,-31.02248 36.67601,-74.52647 72.34955,-97.14631 3.86352,12.84605 -33.53648,33.38016 -38.90883,54.24494 -8.75049,15.43207 -12.7348,39.33093 -33.44072,42.90137 z m 85.20568,0.39644 c -3.77802,-18.04643 19.27101,3.36819 0,0 z m 77.68275,-4.56702 c -8.57611,-11.11373 14.86163,-51.8655 14.65623,-31.34174 -6.1725,9.82035 -7.17031,22.31252 -14.65623,31.34174 z m -73.68275,-7.43298 c 0.61674,-12.69362 18.81883,-47.01956 10.34194,-15.77492 -1.85047,5.24152 -2.14561,16.79985 -10.34194,15.77492 z m 292.02042,-6.13805 c -28.11067,-39.16265 -58.50991,-78.41838 -98.0442,-106.64826 -33.06826,-20.56783 -74.51149,-27.63059 -112.06256,-17.08625 -13.73959,3.03221 -29.07912,-1.2575 -7.77942,-4.90737 23.06883,-1.82798 45.59243,-9.49763 68.80238,-5.36195 38.36968,6.85886 74.98556,27.85433 98.84017,58.9759 20.29363,22.61133 41.57304,44.80871 58.0625,70.36517 5.17252,7.46401 -4.06299,7.37445 -7.81887,4.66276 z m -379.43709,-1.29446 c 0.12767,-25.29428 22.14997,-44.43169 34.86222,-64.65498 23.48782,-30.26804 53.73129,-55.67439 88.39169,-72.03732 16.60144,1.47683 -21.79984,19.71904 -31.01978,25.59585 -19.93518,12.57228 -32.54571,33.39325 -51.4292,47.21112 -10.86698,19.54393 -26.55155,36.42626 -33.88524,57.7085 -0.66763,2.8351 -3.28175,7.07317 -6.91969,6.17683 z m 151,-2.36155 c -5.33007,-14.70681 11.60534,8.27956 0,0 z M 558.71256,546.67 c -25.51396,-34.76073 -55.38792,-67.0509 -89.53929,-93.42966 -22.19339,-10.7267 -43.65708,-26.27905 -69.34509,-26.96121 -16.35597,-10.65626 -38.44133,9.42062 -49.09746,-1.26984 20.38909,-15.76589 48.50961,-5.91094 72.56231,-0.87287 29.17577,10.35315 58.65758,23.3534 79.68133,47.10876 24.96468,17.78604 38.24235,47.13165 59.94821,68.14972 3.13906,3.38994 1.69561,10.12742 -4.21001,7.2751 z m -394.99852,-7.99851 c -4.01736,-12.86262 31.43533,-43.64342 16.30412,-19.28591 -6.60326,5.13895 -5.48514,20.34722 -16.30412,19.28591 z m 185.47258,-2.63073 c 6.46445,-12.78435 43.59713,-12.32874 15.25639,-1.73905 -3.6371,1.24669 -14.97641,10.96708 -15.25639,1.73905 z m 213.56336,-8.66506 c -8.76584,-17.67065 -32.04449,-40.24371 -36.52384,-51.15166 19.12926,5.67345 39.33842,24.89524 50.43607,37.57152 -8.30926,-6.93728 -31.32536,-13.91521 -13.93429,1.90207 5.073,5.30402 16.85735,24.34711 0.0221,11.67807 z M 161.66433,513.344 c -11.25373,-14.14317 32.61811,-33.64704 12.15103,-11.96221 -2.75738,3.86773 -4.60664,19.81511 -12.15103,11.96221 z m 26.58565,-8.75897 c -6.20836,-12.82676 23.80328,-23.17601 7.86501,-4.86752 -1.32827,2.56434 -4.36091,7.29218 -7.86501,4.86752 z m 383.25,-11.29427 c -29.25533,-17.48104 -44.98914,-49.82524 -74.50453,-66.98647 -17.46026,-16.39485 -37.53591,-27.11158 -60.44502,-33.97527 -26.30034,-10.01049 -54.30715,-12.48869 -82.29136,-10.92291 -22.82283,0.14644 -46.55384,4.02816 -68.048,8.62914 -34.65784,12.1331 -60.56893,39.08472 -89.8497,60.05184 -21.30148,4.46299 13.45974,-21.55687 21.32142,-25.16929 19.02258,-19.43758 44.75895,-30.60402 68.64053,-42.42714 23.80556,-1.61158 47.08496,-6.12506 70.75441,-9.04372 23.19556,-3.5517 44.7041,4.46574 67.30076,7.34234 20.53443,6.00056 41.56532,11.59534 58.42721,26.06115 23.3529,11.86612 40.91522,31.54214 60.9542,47.86679 -1.31062,15.80418 48.24575,33.99854 27.74008,38.57354 l 0,0 z m -291.85764,-0.69097 c 12.46744,-16.75641 35.43474,-19.16742 52.69513,-28.96071 11.00925,-9.88905 57.52856,-7.05602 24.05243,0.0138 -26.77454,2.94483 -48.54721,20.0507 -73.50958,28.33565 l -3.23798,0.6113 0,0 z m -123.62508,-4.49567 c 6.56587,-17.20132 11.47951,5.74195 0,0 z m 25.23272,-1.41638 c 9.02526,-30.07085 40.67411,-43.74645 63.44226,-61.99156 21.31011,-21.34949 51.22509,-31.79736 81.08934,-31.99588 30.4484,-8.69719 62.91199,-5.25909 93.01566,2.87892 10.21714,4.00792 48.17657,10.48674 39.96393,19.37433 -21.37537,-5.41079 -41.45501,-16.01884 -63.56889,-17.92158 -26.31347,-9.71085 -53.86764,-3.31896 -79.98949,3.00748 -41.18261,3.95946 -72.28285,33.34771 -103.80844,56.88932 -10.20472,9.38949 -15.56102,26.37437 -30.14437,29.75897 z m 20.75,-4.10337 c 13.28703,-24.03785 39.21404,-36.4984 59.24469,-54.00841 30.73621,-19.41564 67.47192,-27.46119 103.43077,-28.57976 22.95023,-0.76056 44.89011,6.63308 66.32212,12.52789 13.9762,1.61292 35.1896,20.9459 42.65032,16.24345 -19.54542,-27.84838 27.53375,12.85244 35.06945,20.42525 13.06289,5.30061 27.47245,30.38396 4.70254,19.28292 -14.67781,-21.17293 -36.46011,-32.43364 -60.36243,-40.21132 -37.4929,-20.73022 -81.96466,-22.36421 -123.70886,-18.82027 -35.73187,4.64095 -67.43255,24.16019 -92.94361,48.84599 -15.44828,0.62284 -19.83981,26.22002 -34.40499,24.29426 z m 42.66667,2.03972 c 9.67807,-22.43519 41.10524,-29.56742 55.38906,-43.42545 1.04668,13.13661 19.76006,3.61615 1.52734,11.13441 -22.23745,5.19631 -36.93987,26.61705 -56.9164,32.29104 z m -81.66667,-5.91025 c 8.68701,-24.87136 20.14098,14.25695 0,0 z m 410.5,-10.42308 c -23.03829,-19.69374 -52.9394,-45.02377 -69.69655,-63.73045 26.57917,-1.04861 40.58083,29.80402 59.32679,45.43374 7.97615,1.87494 33.13966,34.3375 10.36976,18.29671 z m -413.83333,0.33333 c -8.42754,-14.41679 26.53302,-16.82488 5.18115,-3.47103 l -2.38808,1.66317 -2.79307,1.80786 z M 179.71256,465.67 c -4.49741,-16.36846 15.68988,1.74536 0,0 z m -8.71258,-14.41062 c -15.74488,-13.99908 27.65343,-25.17334 32.45936,-40.53448 10.9827,-12.87681 30.78571,-8.05984 10.2022,5.27041 -16.9078,6.71245 -34.88761,31.6838 -42.66156,35.26407 z m 410.08844,-2.46862 c -19.04722,-15.01261 -33.43438,-35.13232 -53.5233,-48.98469 -13.91289,-20.74813 -37.4512,-26.42587 -57.87087,-37.82332 -13.04401,-14.47837 -46.11516,-10.65084 -50.7036,-26.22687 24.00245,3.22158 46.09361,13.9454 67.25059,25.25476 29.88283,14.51685 53.91107,38.28646 78.71395,59.84125 4.77225,2.15067 36.26106,45.43208 16.13323,27.93887 z M 302.99998,438.09548 c 7.42692,-11.84364 47.89426,-11.72433 38.82003,-8.04638 -13.21613,1.39859 -25.10232,10.95626 -38.82003,8.04638 z m -142.5,-7.80472 c 2.72542,-8.47003 9.11028,4.30727 0,0 z m 6.5,-5.77682 c -0.59223,-14.82058 45.41088,-30.56704 20.22391,-11.40117 -6.2882,1.93797 -14.23761,15.41898 -20.22391,11.40117 z m 136,1.82834 c 11.34247,-9.32384 51.2537,-18.63713 46.50807,-9.37753 -14.99851,5.21729 -30.90092,6.93304 -46.50807,9.37753 z m 276.75,-5.91263 c -20.32811,-26.5499 -49.37987,-44.99867 -77.87567,-61.68269 -35.02099,-18.43307 -74.41359,-38.9802 -115.09897,-27.36437 -24.1377,5.94379 -50.54573,1.02699 -73.27536,12.90817 -9.95175,1.60508 -44.1048,19.71312 -39.15256,7.20501 24.96118,-9.81844 49.33974,-23.20615 76.89504,-23.08976 24.7837,-1.99987 49.36848,-9.08387 74.23229,-6.76804 26.44869,5.24165 52.01421,14.11711 75.34154,27.81217 26.47434,10.64294 46.96079,31.52404 70.08347,47.48468 4.78703,2.28096 24.27763,29.04918 8.85022,23.49483 z m -416.0625,-9.78472 c 4.85308,-25.44368 35.00515,-32.96586 53.95943,-45.75316 30.72849,-18.90301 63.78504,-33.85428 97.48926,-46.54527 22.7143,-5.88988 47.07302,-9.34331 70.23956,-5.35272 -9.44448,9.06091 -40.52269,3.55333 -58.18433,9.88424 -43.40068,12.16884 -83.36533,34.40134 -122.07422,56.86633 -12.75773,11.26016 -31.31597,20.74449 -41.4297,30.90058 z m 319.5625,-13.05859 c -14.48307,-21.91113 33.4154,18.21661 2.49859,2.50529 -0.83287,-0.8351 -1.66573,-1.67019 -2.49859,-2.50529 z m -285.25,1.79701 c 14.99729,-18.60104 38.12159,-27.50363 58.56362,-38.07918 24.36104,0.77894 -17.67395,15.28729 -24.82614,21.28851 -10.67883,5.42534 -21.71718,17.78453 -33.73748,16.79067 z m 27.5399,-0.028 c 16.19086,-15.38113 38.58787,-21.50132 56.62618,-34.31546 25.10561,-11.18103 50.82056,-21.58752 78.77382,-22.09039 22.8209,-7.77738 44.36819,-0.23814 66.07169,7.73097 10.21874,2.3287 47.11617,17.33172 18.18154,11.30802 -41.21936,-15.64917 -87.04885,-14.91794 -129.36918,-4.28523 -27.09929,10.59308 -51.84953,25.87196 -77.34187,39.47398 -4.12562,1.51619 -8.53136,2.40847 -12.94218,2.17811 z m 285.98148,-1.04094 c -17.28645,-11.75055 -37.53861,-15.28242 -57.56637,-18.28259 -32.025,-9.11023 -65.54114,-16.80015 -98.98577,-14.48503 -18.89553,-0.85432 -39.93843,13.19806 -56.82319,7.93758 22.03114,-9.13855 46.36919,-13.40988 69.94417,-15.22528 35.45977,-2.50213 69.077,10.28128 103.25573,17.4221 7.63517,1.90933 51.32684,16.94461 40.17543,22.63322 z m -347.85471,-10.6903 c 7.78482,-27.14761 41.71583,-32.03266 62.62167,-45.84939 35.74162,-14.56712 67.96981,-38.70181 107.3005,-43.32 10.451,-4.32612 53.62345,-1.05809 21.17499,4.41769 -23.14755,2.18222 -45.92159,6.512 -67.00968,17.13029 -28.30102,7.98948 -50.82123,28.33661 -78.24779,38.53127 -16.05484,8.53897 -30.40513,19.31843 -45.83969,29.09014 z m 414.56857,-3.40823 c -27.6216,-17.79117 -55.66611,-34.67229 -84.93129,-49.57974 -20.37533,-11.24939 -43.77845,-14.759 -65.03718,-23.61418 -17.73574,4.02863 -44.07257,-5.00869 -52.86316,-11.77623 23.47285,-4.84268 49.63265,5.57924 73.29018,10.5954 20.8666,8.06621 42.8813,14.96898 61.87273,26.36548 5.66787,8.25062 37.51155,19.53538 19.20266,1.66538 -36.43145,-21.35473 -75.27535,-40.27624 -117.59376,-46.67299 -44.08615,-6.28815 -90.83066,-5.53149 -131.43919,14.70525 -11.04738,2.48791 -38.54421,25.68306 -40.34074,8.91506 18.30811,-9.11952 41.88113,-17.33934 64.18891,-23.88125 40.97306,-13.78327 86.51444,-16.19777 127.75007,-2.22782 39.61348,8.45548 76.26921,26.58822 108.73465,50.56461 7.85879,19.90367 46.22562,29.50795 42.92099,48.81521 l -2.09329,-1.00515 -3.66158,-2.86903 0,0 z m 0.90879,-26.4801 c -20.7757,-16.11341 -40.56033,-33.45073 -63.46093,-46.5548 -29.64708,-21.24477 -66.32678,-26.63484 -100.62119,-36.4017 -26.5554,-4.5234 -54.6614,-8.36345 -81.16798,-1.27696 -24.65865,4.22064 -48.34098,14.69985 -73.23528,19.16663 -19.01991,8.08585 -41.82437,27.4241 -59.45813,27.08729 23.47911,-18.14091 49.64867,-33.78339 79.21805,-41.11634 24.59308,-8.31647 50.42102,-8.2262 75.0106,-16.77079 23.18857,2.46929 47.57364,2.43421 70.39451,8.28061 45.72374,9.55243 90.54829,28.2016 127.99929,56.82865 11.14888,1.24618 43.99411,41.26286 25.60752,31.04064 l -0.28646,-0.28325 c 0,0 0,2e-5 0,2e-5 z m -415.56143,2.68865 c 12.07236,-20.35199 40.7357,-20.74241 57.97846,-35.25341 17.0663,-12.51377 19.42511,5.53371 1.31641,8.13737 -18.92126,11.77455 -40.12119,15.74577 -59.29487,27.11604 z m 12.08407,-22.80032 c -0.62195,-16.0443 17.90556,7.68251 0,0 z m 14.98622,-8.08595 c 4.15051,-14.01566 12.89682,3.14527 0,0 z m -18.98622,-3.91405 c 2.46594,-13.66303 49.12553,-29.82242 22.82336,-9.73688 -6.25619,5.41372 -14.12367,10.67052 -22.82336,9.73688 z m 401.06536,-1.33335 c -22.33033,-7.64469 -37.06273,-28.43266 -59.64027,-36.07944 -39.50264,-20.77247 -84.09955,-28.09581 -128.04856,-32.32233 -28.67509,-7.98958 -55.30333,4.21151 -83.70351,4.83829 -24.75531,6.42595 -48.02443,17.74197 -72.45556,25.19543 -1.24741,-17.23201 35.89102,-14.33767 48.8934,-26.27148 19.99733,-9.21744 44.00581,-1.07942 64.10202,-11.57126 21.45017,-4.98229 42.88122,0.68398 64.09343,1.96942 21.11013,10.68012 44.18015,7.27113 66.46629,12.14112 32.78766,9.96391 63.47413,26.92124 89.07887,49.46785 30.52076,14.10503 -18.06825,-24.36927 -26.79239,-32.14583 -24.33079,-21.66126 -57.30869,-27.18282 -87.59362,-34.93622 -33.90353,2.29771 -67.75442,-16.06116 -101.07608,-3.61595 -11.0695,-6.45715 -45.96331,17.62023 -40.8014,1.41993 23.99438,-9.3945 50.54557,-11.92133 76.12701,-12.44773 25.23806,1.18876 48.53502,12.07748 74.13376,10.37135 35.80071,0.29754 68.056,18.34637 93.79178,41.99132 8.61266,2.85062 54.42268,51.21936 23.42483,41.99553 z M 179.66665,302.62409 c 10.42076,-23.03298 62.43646,-23.00337 20.1966,-6.27896 -6.64261,2.37891 -13.51503,4.02287 -20.1966,6.27896 z m 26.35061,-0.53952 c 14.07129,-17.22644 22.68828,8.75973 0,0 z m -31.01728,-11.60672 c 7.00194,-15.52811 12.07221,5.90881 0,0 z m 395.01078,-3.6741 c -3.51296,-18.77476 18.09758,5.42849 0,0 z m -382.81078,-3.71299 c 13.21487,-21.96244 45.49001,-24.31792 64.50884,-39.71767 2.32901,3.48237 -4.0147,16.86433 -8.93947,19.83699 -16.27187,-2.99967 -39.71563,15.60779 -55.56937,19.88068 z m 371.51277,-3.42057 c -7.45606,-23.94188 -36.87756,-27.68726 -54.26596,-42.14473 -21.36782,-6.27588 -41.59047,-15.07989 -61.57624,-24.78874 -22.33465,-8.39706 -46.61649,-6.93264 -69.86829,-11.11754 -22.915,2.91946 -45.7945,4.37033 -68.48506,10.57915 -26.72075,6.6724 -52.7915,18.09956 -75.47268,32.87842 -16.33531,-13.3309 30.11964,-21.85906 41.59654,-29.98166 25.66727,-8.41628 51.36608,-17.42865 78.71879,-18.85404 27.76308,-4.37256 55.27819,1.54338 82.51821,5.42257 37.80187,12.73176 75.30997,27.51094 109.2768,48.62878 9.56461,1.56368 43.19584,31.85119 17.55789,29.37779 z M 256.38402,258.84917 c 2.92326,-18.3031 36.26273,-2.36984 8.60314,-2.71256 -3.33585,-1.47636 -5.95312,6.88178 -8.60314,2.71256 z m -57.13404,-2.22069 c -6.47369,-22.75548 39.65666,-7.40421 8.35076,-3.15443 -2.47524,1.41656 -5.11144,5.60313 -8.35076,3.15443 z m 65.41667,-12.00439 c 12.1061,-15.48912 39.48646,-21.52287 57.59146,-23.95127 -1.46032,14.17688 -32.464,10.76578 -44.05355,23.40719 -4.33902,1.45606 -9.09917,1.75087 -13.53791,0.54408 z m 279.44231,-7.30694 c -31.23647,-16.42122 -63.43574,-30.75616 -97.04951,-41.63326 -23.12817,-9.14887 -49.31134,-8.74214 -73.9248,-10.0661 -24.53285,4.28451 -50.0482,-0.1229 -73.75777,7.81841 -13.78705,2.20569 -50.02931,26.06321 -51.83294,10.2201 23.16703,-4.34974 42.01071,-21.99222 66.43487,-22.06188 26.50777,-2.68343 53.12753,-3.20066 79.48595,-5.31783 22.6871,1.73814 44.02991,4.79721 64.46225,15.0057 25.54113,8.5896 49.57119,21.34918 75.56693,28.62222 2.31425,4.3347 33.68357,24.82521 10.61502,17.41264 z m -339.88209,-2.69007 c 1.25855,-17.89053 53.16773,-30.59657 23.96344,-9.98643 -7.53927,4.32223 -15.77769,7.17607 -23.96344,9.98643 z m 248.94826,-2.98783 c -32.21204,-7.26772 -64.97712,-11.92768 -98.0607,-9.37541 -11.78674,2.25257 -32.07516,-5.1687 -8.99493,-7.20287 27.18847,-1.27336 55.11306,-2.48729 81.96893,2.4782 4.42509,-0.67447 42.94707,15.1302 25.0867,14.10008 z m 65.55688,-27.34849 c -26.08728,-14.2558 -54.98216,-21.63282 -82.60491,-32.0831 -11.25155,-1.67105 -57.80987,-5.66912 -24.43958,-10.4214 29.3125,0.58422 55.33143,16.573 83.41166,23.36767 6.57147,-0.22813 54.45835,26.82438 23.63283,19.13683 z m -284.8703,-6.08545 c 11.80653,-17.92928 36.31908,-19.83518 53.96393,-29.59416 23.74316,-3.43395 49.38029,-16.38707 71.51693,-11.57011 -26.20945,13.55707 -55.3263,12.83524 -81.78735,23.74494 -14.33857,6.36496 -28.42776,13.44219 -43.69351,17.41933 z m 119.67098,-23.86163 c 5.89853,-16.57435 19.57887,6.75381 0,0 z m 31.02114,-10.96579 c -1.65201,-6.62429 5.49219,1.59951 0,0 z m -12.55385,-2.95479 c 3.58134,-11.98189 3.92855,9.66952 0,0 z m -3.45729,-9.06324 c 0.64804,-5.53702 5.30151,3.33078 0,0 z" />
  </g>
</svg>
  

</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid inline svg because it's not cachable. I wanted to use the the _use_ element from svg

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `viewbox` attribute has the wrong value. If you exported your svg from a program, double-check it there. In any other case, check your source.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the fingerprint file directly you do so via a viewBox (viewBox="0 0 431.72714 626.25482" preserveAspectRatio="none) When you display the file via the `<use>` element you reference the inner `<g>` element and the viewBox transform is omitted.

The simplest way around this is to [add in the missing viewBox transform via an inner `<svg>` element](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQOEXx).

```
<html>
  <body>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" id="parent" width="100%" height="100%">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 431.72714 626.25482" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <use xlink:href="/assets/svg/fingerprint_2.svg#fingerprint"></use>
        </svg>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively if all you're doing is displaying the fingerprint, adjust the outer `<svg`> viewBox and then you won't need an inner `<svg>` element.